# Unable to use variable to filter a specific AD Group in Get-ADGroup

Tags: powershell, directory

I can query using the exact AD Group name like in the example below:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupCategory -eq "Security" -and name -eq "dummygroup"} -SearchBase "OU=Application,OU=SCSX,OU=Groups,OU=Unity,DC=B40,DC=in"
```

if I use the same query replacing the AD group named "dummygroup" with a variable but it doesn't work.

example:

```
$ADGroupname="dummygroup"

Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupCategory -eq "Security" -and name -eq "$ADGroupname"} -SearchBase "OU=Application,OU=SCSX,OU=Groups,OU=Unity,DC=B40,DC=in"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the Double Quotes from the filter:

```
$ADGroupname="dummygroup"

Get-ADGroup -filter {GroupCategory -eq "Security" -and name -eq $ADGroupname} `
-SearchBase "OU=Application,OU=SCSX,OU=Groups,OU=Unity,DC=B40,DC=in"
```